# Question about StringJoin and Join

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Consider

```
Join[Range[3], {Range[3]}]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}}`

and

```
StringJoin["abc", {"abc"}]
```

> `"abcabc"`

Both expressions contain a list and a nested list, but the results are different. Why?

Comment: Because those are different functions. "All lists are ignored:" - second example in StringJoin.

Comment: You ask "Why?" Because Wolfram Research, Inc., did it that way. If you have a beef about it, take it up with WRI.

Comment: the alternative would be to throw an error, i suppose that's good enough reason.